# Dropwiazrd @CacheControl not applying cache control headers

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I have a static endpoint in a Dropwizard project that I would like to cache, I've added the `@CacheControl(maxAge = 6, maxAgeUnit = HOURS)` annotation to it. However the response headers have the incorrect header: `Cache-Control: no-cache`.

Debugging with a breakpoint in `CacheControlledResponseFeature`, I can see that the header definitely gets set, but it seems something is overwriting it.

dropwizard version: 2.0.0
jersey version 2.29.1

Answer (score 0):

@pez, I think you need to check whether your target class to cache, CacheControlledResponseFeature, is a [resource class](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/getting-started.html#creating-a-resource-class) or not? Based on this [reading](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/manual/core.html#how-it-s-glued-together), Cache-Control statement should be added to a **resource class**. If you are sure it is a properly set resource, then perhaps you should improve your logging by checking the dropwizard logging doc in this [link](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/manual/core.html#id4) (eg. increase logger level to DEBUG) so you would know when CacheControlledResponseFeature header was reset/overwritten. Peace out.